# MVC mapping to specific column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mapping

I have the following class below.

```
[Bind()]
[Table("Actives", Schema = "Actives")]
public class Active
{
    [Key()]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Du skal angive et nummer for denne aktiv.")]
    [DisplayName("Nummer")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Du skal angive hvilken type aktiven er.")]
    [DisplayName("Aktiv-type")]
    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public ActiveType ActiveType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    [DisplayName("Sted")]
    public Place Place
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

How can I specify that my "Place" and "ActiveType" properties should match to the "Place_ID" and "ActiveType_ID" columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but can't you use the `Name` property for the `Column` attribute?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Du skal angive hvilken type aktiven er.")]
[DisplayName("Aktiv-type")]
[Column(TypeName = "int", Name="ActiveType_ID")]
public ActiveType ActiveType
{
    get;
    set;
}

[Column(TypeName = "int", Name="Place_ID")]
[DisplayName("Sted")]
public Place Place
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Link to MSDN docs on [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696561%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).